# How to show multi notifications in android device

Tags: android, android-c2dm

I'm Navis, I come from VietNamese and I'm a newbie in android developer.
When i make an application i have a problem with Notification in android.
I used C2DM service to integrate push messages for my app. And when receive message from C2DM server, i want my app show information in notification separated. 1 message show in 1 notification. But when i test app, i push message to my android devices, it only show 1 notification. For example, i push 3 message (1, 2, 3). App will display 1 the same position (only update content). So, how can i display in 3 notification separated?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you are passing the same id to notify api.
Change the ID to different one to show different notifications instead of replacing

```
mNotificationManager.notify(_ID, notification);
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I just do it.